# Java's split method has leading blank records that I can't suppress

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

I'm parsing an input file that has multiple keywords preceded by a `+`. The `+` is my delimiter in a `split`, with individual tokens being written to an array. The resulting array includes a blank record in the `[0]` position.

I suspect that `split` is taking the "nothing" before the first token and populating `project[0]`, then moving on to subsequent tokens which all show up as correct.

[Documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) says that this method has a `limit` parameter:

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings
>   will be discarded.

and I found [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389503/how-to-prevent-java-lang-string-split-from-creating-a-leading-empty-string), but the solution proposed, editing out the leading delimiter (I used a `substring(1)` to create a temp field) yielded the same blank record for me.

Code and output appers below. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.lang.*;
//
public class eadd
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String projStrTemp = "";
        String projString = "";
        String[] project = new String[10];
        int contextSOF = 0;
        int projStringSOF = 0;
        int projStringEOF = 0;
       //
        String inputLine = "foo foofoo foo foo @bar.com +foofoofoo +foo1 +foo2 +foo3";
        contextSOF = inputLine.indexOf("@");
        int tempCalc = (inputLine.indexOf("+")) ;
        if (tempCalc == -1) {
            proj StrTemp = "+Uncategorized";
        } else {
            projStringSOF = inputLine.indexOf("+",contextSOF);
            projStrTemp = inputLine.trim().substring(projStringSOF).trim();
        }
        project = projStrTemp.split("\\+");
       //
        System.out.println(projStrTemp+"\n"+projString);
        for(int j=0;j<project.length;j++) {
        System.out.println("Project["+j+"] "+project[j]);
        }
    }

CONSOLE OUTPUT: 
+foofoofoo +foo1 +foo2 +foo3

Project[0]
Project[1] foofoofoo
Project[2] foo1
Project[3] foo2
Project[4] foo3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to remove the first `+` from the string. This way, it won't split before the first keyword:

```java
projStrTemp = inputLine.trim().substring(projStringSOF + 1).trim();
```

---

*Edit:* Personally, I'd go for a more robust solution using regular expressions. This finds all keywords preceded by `+`. It also requires that `+` is preceded by either a space or it's at the start of the line so that words like `3+4` aren't matched.

```java
String inputLine = "+foo 3+4 foofoo foo foo @bar.com +foofoofoo +foo1 +foo2 +foo3";
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)\\+(\\w+)");
Matcher m = re.matcher(inputLine);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks also for the regex. I'm just getting started with, and am still a little intimidated by, regex. But I'll play with that!

Comment: @dwwilson66 Yes, regular expressions are a bit hard to read, but there are tools that can help a lot. Some of them are described in [Software for visually building regular expressions?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27023/software-for-visually-building-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
projStrTemp = inputLine.trim().substring(projStringSOF).trim();
```

to:

```
projStrTemp = inputLine.trim().substring(projStringSOF + 1).trim();
```

If you have a leading delimiter, your array will start with a blank element. It might be worthwhile for you to experiment with `split()` without all the other baggage.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "an+example";

    String[] items = s.split("\\+");
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " = " + items[i]);
    }
}
```

With `String s = "an+example";` it produces:

```
0 = an
1 = example
```

Whereas `String s = "+an+example";` produces:

```
0 = 
1 = an
2 = example
```

Comment: Thanks! worked great! But doesn't that do the same thing (more elegantly, though) as creating a separate variable defined as `ProjStrTemp.substring(1)`? If not, can you help me understand why...

Comment: Yes, `projStrTemp = projStrTemp.substring(1)` would do the same thing. You must remember to assign it to a variable as substring doesn't modify the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

+foofoofoo +foo1 +foo2 +foo3

Splits method splits the string around matches of the given + so the array contains in the first element an empty field (with 5 elements). If you want to get the previous data get inputLine instead the processed projStrTemp that substring from the first + included.