# Time Conversion challenge on Hackerrank returning empty hour

Tags: java, intellij-idea, time

I was attempting the [Time Conversion](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion) challenge on Hackerrank, but for some reason, the hour field in the 24-hour representation always comes out empty. Here's the challenge -

> Problem Statement
>
> Given a time in AM/PM format, convert it to military (24-hour) time.
>
> Note: Midnight is 12:00:00AM on a 12-hour clock and 00:00:00 on a
>   24-hour clock. Noon is 12:00:00PM on a 12-hour clock and 12:00:00 on a
>   24-hour clock.

Another problem seems to be that the seconds always appears to be of 1 digit. For instance, if the input is `07:05:45PM`, my Hackerrank output is `:05:4`.

But, the code runs just fine in IntelliJ on my desktop -

```
1:24:23AM
1
24
23AM
01:24:23

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and

```
07:05:45PM
07
05
45PM
19:05:45

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As there's no way to debug the solution on hackerrank itself, I'm not sure what's wrong. Here's my code -

```
package algorithms.Warmup;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by manishgiri on 1/6/16.
 */
public class TimeConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String time = in.next();
        String[] parts = time.split(":");
        for(String part: parts){
            System.out.println(part);
        }
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        String minutes = (parts[1]);
        String[] last = parts[2].split("");

        String seconds = last[0]+last[1];
        String timeZ = last[2]+last[3];
        String finalHour = "";
        if(timeZ.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")) {
            if(hours == 12) {
                finalHour = Integer.toString(12);
            }
            else {
                finalHour = Integer.toString(hours + 12);
            }
        }
        else if(timeZ.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")) {
            if(hours == 12) {
                finalHour = "00";
            }
            else if(hours == 10 || hours == 11) {
                finalHour = Integer.toString(hours);
            }
            else {
                finalHour = "0"+hours;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalHour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);


    }
}
```

Comment: Since there is no debug. You could replace the split for the last part `AM` and `pm`. You could just check if it `String#contains` `AM` or `PM`. Afterwards you could use `String#replaceAll` with the regex `\\D`. That way you would replace the `AM` and `PM` and would only have the seconds left. Maybe `Hackerrank` does a bad job with the `split("")`. Since it running for me either i can just an other way to solve it that might be working.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. Hope the comments will help to understand the logic.

```
static String timeConversion(String s) {
    // Split the string by :
    String[] sTime = s.split(":");

    int x = 0;

    // if PM and hours >12, add additional 12 to hours
    // for AM and hour = 12, set hour to 00
    if(sTime[sTime.length - 1].contains("PM") && !sTime[0].equals("12"))
        x = 12;

    String val1 = "";
    if(x == 12)
        val1 = (Integer.parseInt(sTime[0]) + x) + "";
    else {
        if(sTime[0].equals("12") && sTime[sTime.length - 1].contains("AM"))
            val1 = "00";
        else
            val1 = sTime[0];
    }

    // merge the string and return the result
    String result = val1 + ":" + sTime[1] + ":" + sTime[2].substring(0,2);
    return result;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why there is inconsistency between your JRE environment and Hackerrank environment. But if we came to your question, in hackerrank your code splits part[2] into 5 parts, leading empty string.

Which means if you update

```
String seconds = last[0]+last[1];
String timeZ = last[2]+last[3];
```

as

```
String seconds = last[1]+last[2];
String timeZ = last[3]+last[4];
```

it should run,

and to prevent initial empty string, there is some suggestions you can find below:

[How to prevent java.lang.String.split() from creating a leading empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389503/how-to-prevent-java-lang-string-split-from-creating-a-leading-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for hackerrank -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String time = in.next();
        int hours;
        String hrs = time.substring(0,2);
        hours = Integer.parseInt(hrs);
        String mins = time.substring(3,5);
        String secs = time.substring(6,8);
        String am_pm = time.substring(time.length()-2,time.length());
        if(am_pm.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") && !hrs.equalsIgnoreCase("12")){  
            hours += 12;
            hrs = Integer.toString(hours);
        }
        else if(am_pm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") && hrs.equalsIgnoreCase("12")){
            hours = 0;
            hrs = "00";
        }
        System.out.println(hrs+":"+mins+":"+secs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String time = in.next();

    String[] sTime = time.split(":");

    int x = sTime[sTime.length - 1].contains("PM") ? 12 : 0 ;

    String val1 = (x == 12) ?  (Integer.parseInt(sTime[0]) + x) + "" :  (sTime[0].equals("12") ? "00" : sTime[0]);

    String result = val1 + ":" + sTime[1] + ":" + sTime[2].substring(0,2);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String timecon(String s) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, 2));
    int test = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, 2));
    if ((s.substring(0, 2).equals("12")) && s.substring(8, 10).equals("AM")) {
        return "00" + ":" + s.substring(3, 8);
    } else if (s.substring(0, 2).equals("12") && (s.substring(8, 10).equals("PM"))) {
        return s.substring(0, 8);
    } else if (s.substring(8, 10).equals("AM")) {
        return s.substring(0, 8);
    }
    else {
        return test + 12 + ":" + s.substring(3, 8);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this in Java for Time Conversion Hackerrank**

```
  /*
 * Complete the timeConversion function below.
 */
static String timeConversion(String s) {
    String h,m,sec;

    h = s.substring(0,2);
    m = s.substring(3,5);
    sec = s.substring(6,8);

    if(s.contains("PM") && !h.equals("12")){
        int inc = 12;
        inc += Integer.parseInt(h);
        h = inc + "";
    }
    if(s.contains("AM") && h.equals("12")){
        h = "00";
    }
    String milTime = h + ":" + m + ":" + sec;
    return milTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String timeConversion(String s) {

int h = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));

if (h == 12) h = 0;

if (s.substring(8,9).equals("P")) h = h + 12;

return String.format("%02d", h) + s.substring(2,8);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string timeConversion(string s)
{
      var idate = DateTime.Parse(s);
      var odate = idate.TimeOfDay;
      return odate.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the most compact code, i think

```
function timeConversion(s) {
    // Write your code here
    let time=s.slice(0,10).split(':');
    // return(time);
    if((time[0]<12)&&(time[2].includes('PM'))){
        time[0]=parseInt(time[0])+12;
    }
    if((time[0]==12)&&(time[2].includes('AM'))){
        time[0]='00';
    }
    // return(time);
    return(time.join(':').slice(0,8));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def timeConversion(s):
    # time_r=s[:-2]
    am_pm=s[-2:]
    if am_pm=='PM' and s[:2]!='12':
    s=str(int(s[:2])+12) + s[2:]
    if am_pm=='AM' and s[:2]=='12':
        s="00" + s[2:]
    return s[:-2]

print(timeConversion("07:05:45PM"))
```