# String split method returning first element as empty using regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to get the digits from the expression `[1..1]`, using Java's `split` method. I'm using the regex expression `^\\[|\\.{2}|\\]$` inside `split`. But the `split` method returning me String array with first value as empty, and then "1" inside index 1 and 2 respectively. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing in this regex expression, so that I only get the digits in the returned String array from `split` method?

Comment: Either update to Java 8 or [do same research](https://www.google.de/search?q=java+split+first+empty). This question is already answered a lot of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array)

Comment: Why can't you just do a find with `\\d`?

Comment: @cricket_007: I would suggest `\\d+` since the numbers can probably be larger than `9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use matching. Change your expression to:

```
`^\[(.*?)\.\.(.*)\]$`
```

And get your results from the two captured groups.

As for why `split` acts this way, it's simple: you asked it to split on the `[` character, but there's still an *"empty string"* between the start of the string and the first `[` character.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is matching `[` and `..` and `]`. Thus it will split at this occurrences.

You should not use a split but match each number in your string using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You've set it up such that `[`, `]` and `..` are delimiters.  `Split` will return an empty first index because the first character in your string `[1..1]` is a delimiter.  I would strip delimiters from the front and end of your string, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389503/how-to-prevent-java-lang-string-split-from-creating-a-leading-empty-string).

So, something like

```
input.replaceFirst("^[", "").split("^\\[|\\.{2}|\\]$");
```

Or, use regex and regex groups (such as the other answers in this question) more directly rather than through split.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regex to *capture* the numbers? This will be more effective less error prone. In that case the regex looks like:

```
^\[(\d+)\.{2}(\d+)\]$
```

And you can capture them with:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^\\[(\\d+)\\.{2}(\\d+)\\]$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(matcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
    int range_from = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int range_to = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
}
```

with `range_from` and `range_to` the integers you can no work with.

The advantage is that the pattern will fail on strings that make not much sense like `..3[4`, etc.